# Start Activity By Listactivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to start a activity everytime an item is clicked on a ListView
i'm using database in my project and using global varaibles in my project
but not able to start GalleryFileActivity activity  in project
If you need to know to each of the sections will also provide
Thank you for your continued efforts to advance the perfection

public class DataListView extends ListActivity {

```
final private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
private String Path;
final private ArrayList<String> pikh = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final global folder = ((global)getApplicationContext());
    openAndQueryDatabase();

    displayResultList();


}
private void displayResultList() {
    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    tView.setText("data is");
    getListView().addHeaderView(tView);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

    ListView lstView = getListView();


   lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);        
   lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
    public void onListItemClick(
            ListView parent, View v, int position,long id, global folder)
            {
        String pos=results.get(position-1);
        super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
                Toast.makeText(this,
                    "You have selected "  + results.get(position-1) ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                folder.setsubfolder (pos);
            **startActivity(new Intent(this,GalleryFileActivity.class));**
            }

            public void onClick(View view) {
                ListView lstView = getListView();

            }

private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT Path, Header FROM resource1  " 
                 , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    Path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Path"));
                    String Header = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Header"));

                    results.add( Path + "    " + Header);


                }while (c.moveToNext()) ;

            } 
        }           
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (newDB != null) 
            newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            newDB.close();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The code looks about right.

Sounds like you may not have `GalleryFileActivity` declared in your manifest.

Check your logcat output - there's probably an exception in there that mentions this.

Comment: I examined all applications and hitting Vaio list is not intended to Activity
How can I go with a Activity by ListActivity???

Comment: Are you trying to start the standard phone photo gallery application? Or is GalleryFileActivity an activity that you've written?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the problem is go to a Activity by listactivity Global and I'm not sure it serves the function

Comment: Your startActivity call is correct if GalleryFileActivity is in your application and is registered as an activity in your manifest. Can you post the logcat output in your question?